# On the popup form - Why Form submission is loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this page https://spa.micra-anglia.gr/ if you go to "Purifying Detox face & body ritual" section and click on this title you can see that a sidebar is showing. On this sidebar, I am calling ajax to get some content.

On this content, I have a WordPress form that is showing using shortcode.

Now, If I press the Submit button (Blue one) it's reloading the page. Why?

but if you check the same form on this page: https://spa.micra-anglia.gr/test-form/ you can see the page is not loading.

Can you tell me what is happening here?

**My JS code for the pulling content:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click','.custom-ajax-link,.open_sidebar_post, .post-title a,.post .post-item .post-thumbnail a',function(e){
        loadPostEvent(e);
        return false;
    });

    function loadPostEvent(event){
        var el = $(event.currentTarget);
        var url = el.attr('href');
        if(typeof url == "undefined" || url  === ''){
            url = el.attr('data-href');
            if(typeof url == "undefined" || url  === '') {
                var classList = el.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
                $.each(classList, function (idx, item) {
                    if(item.indexOf('MAINURL') >=0){
                        url = item.replace('MAINURL',main_url).trim();
                    }
                })
            }

        }
        $('.sidebar-post').empty();
        $('.sidebar-post').append('<span class="close-sidebar-post"></span><span class="loading-circle"><i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i></span>');
        if(!$('body').hasClass('open-right-sidebar')){
            var scrollbarWidth = getScrollbarWidth();
            if(scrollbarWidth > 0){
                $('body').css('padding-right',scrollbarWidth+'px');
            }
            $('body').addClass('open-right-sidebar');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>',
            data: {action: 'load_sidebar_post', url: url},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res){
                if(res !== ''){
                    if(!$('#vc_accordion_script-js').length){
                        $('<script>')
                            .attr('id', 'vc_accordion_script-js')
                            .attr('src', '<?php echo get_site_url()?>/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/vc_accordion/vc-accordion.min.js?ver=6.7.0')
                            .appendTo('head');
                    }
                    $('.sidebar-post').empty();
                    $('.sidebar-post').append('<div class="sidebar-content portfolio-template-default single single-portfolio"><span class="close-sidebar-post"></span>'+res+'</div>');
                    window.vc_js();
                    console.log(Kalium);
                    galleryContentPost();
                    Kalium.Media.VideoJS.initVideoElements();
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: you didn't show the html code but I want to ask: there's a chance that the button your are talking about has no `type="button"` attribute set? you even call it submit button. Every button `type="submit"` will fire the submit event of the form enclosing it. And to be exact any button not having the type attribute set will default to `type="submit"`. So probably the page you are comparing to, calls event.preventDefault() in its `onSubmit` event handler

Comment: then why on this page https://spa.micra-anglia.gr/test-form/ on form submission the page is not loading?